# Got “success” without receiving any message with GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I've tried to send a notification from server to my app on my phone and I get "success" but my phone doesn't receive anything, I'm using Google Cloud Messaging, although I received instance ID with message in my server and use it to send a message.

```
    public class GCMIntentService extends GcmListenerService{


    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "from:" + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "message:" + message);

        sendNotification(message);
    }
     private void sendNotification(String message){
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){    
             NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle("New Message")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSound)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());    
        }    
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.abdul_majeed.alruthea.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.abdul_majeed.alruthea.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

....

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">      
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.abdul_majeed.alruthea" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </receiver>   
    <service
        android:name=".GCMIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

======================================

Comment: Are the GCM messages succesfully delivered to your device? Does your adb logs show any message about "from: xxx" "message: yyy" ?

Comment: Hi, consider adding the server-side code also. Are you only checking the http code from the GCM servers or are you checking the payload also for the number of successful devices?

Comment: Are you still using C2DM (Android Cloud to Device Messaging)? Based on your Manifest file, it seems that you're still using the old version. C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012 and service shut down completely last October 20, 2015. C2DM accepts no new users and grants no new quotas. C2DM developers are strongly encouraged to move on Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). GCM is next to generation of C2DM.

Here's a Official Google Documentation on how to Migrate fromn C2DM to GCM: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in debug mode and check if the device is receiving it. You may try to test the gcm connection here: https://console.developers.google.com

Link below is the Official Google Documentation for GCM, you may try to check step by step procedure on how to setup a GCM client App: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/